# Can the sitemap contain URLs only differentiated by a # (hash)?

Tags: url, sitemap, single-page-application, hash

My website is a single page and uses the anchor tags to navigate.

When I generated my sitemap using an online tool, it generated 2 URLs:

```xml
<url>
  <loc>https://www.example.com/</loc>
  <lastmod>2018-01-27T19:56:44+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://www.example.com/index.html</loc>
  <lastmod>2018-01-27T19:56:44+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
```

Should I go through and add in my other pages (links / sections of the page) i.e. `https://www.example.com/#features-list`, or will Google count that as a dupe because of `index.html`?

Comment: I would say no for one simple reason. You do not need a sitemap! Plain and simple. If your one page site is indexed, then the sitemap is of no value whatsoever. Sitemaps are not what most SEOs tell you they are. For most all sites, they are not only unnecessary, but a distraction. Delete any sitemap. You are wasting your time and energy. Cheers!!

Comment: And you don't need an entry for both `/` and `/index.html` - that is presumably the same page? (How did the sitemap generator find `index.html`?)

Comment: Not sure, I just entered my website address: https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

Comment: It sounds like it is a crawler based sitemap generator.  If it is finding two URLs for the home page, I wouldn't use it.   Google expects the sitemap to only contain preferred canonical URLs.   No URLs of duplicate pages should be allowed.

Comment: Do your fragment URLs that have a hash show different content to users?

Comment: I've removed the index.html version now and just left the first one in place. Yes, they do - although the URL doens't change (it's handled via JS). You can visit the links via the anchor and still get to the content i.e https://www.myserviceplanner.com/#about